# how to find space contained records using talend integration

Tags: integration, talend

i want to retrieve space contained records using talend integration.
My records are:

```
id   name
1    India
2    aus tralia
3    singa pore
```

i want to retrieve space contained records from above example
ex:

```
2    aus tralia
3    singa pore
```

Thank advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these records are in existing data flow you can use tFilterRow component with "Use advanced mode". Somethin like this:

1. Sample input rows
   [image: talend sample rows]
2. How to use tFilterRow with advanced mode

[image: tFilterRow with advanced]